# Java - Does accessing a static global variable from another class take more time?

Tags: java, performance, variables, static, global-variables

Say I have a static variable in some class, and it's not accessed through a getter, is it still faster to access it by assigning it to a local variable in another class (inside a function) than accessing it directly. How about when the variable is declared inside the same class through whose object I'm accessing it? I'm asking this for cases where I need to use the variable many times inside one function.

Comment: There's a small amount of extra time on the first time it's accessed, because the class has to be loaded.  But after the JIT has had a chance to run, there shouldn't be any difference between any type of variable access.  (Methods that may be virtual (inherited) take a bit of extra time on the average, I think.)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're accessing it millions of times in a tight loop, you likely will never notice a difference.

Beware premature optimization. Write the code the way it makes most sense, then optimize it later, if you actually see a performance issue, using a profiler.

Comment: Aside from practical reasons, I'm also asking simply because I'm curious.

Comment: "Beware premature optimization" is the answer, though it never hurts to be curious.

Comment: If you are accessing the variable millions of times in a tight loop the runtime engine will optimize​ away the variable access.

Answer (score 0):

If the program has access to a variable, be it local, instance, or class level, or from another class's members, there's no reason to believe that any one will be faster to access than any other. On top of that, the runtime optimizer will likely enregister, eliminate, or otherwise optimize the access, particularly if it's frequent. More significant to program speed will be cache locality and GC (garbage collection). However the variable is scoped, a variable access is a a variable access is a variable access.